# Create network interface using pptp vpn

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn

My scenario is the following, need to create a network interface in Ubuntu using pptp (or other like OpenVpn or l2pt) without interfering with other interfaces, pptp would only be used with a command like this:

```
wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO - --bind-address 10.200.21.3
```

(Where `10.200.21.3` is the IP interface pptp)

I managed to do all this as follows

```
sudo apt-get install linux-pptp network-manager-pptp
sudo pptpsetup --create VPN2 --server 186.227.xx.xx --username MyUser --encrypt
sudo pon VPN2
```

Then the ppp0 interface is created with a dynamic local IP (e.g. `10.200.21.3`) however still without access, then:

```
ip route add default via 10.200.21.3 dev ppp0 table 10
ip rule add from 10.200.21.3 table 10
```

After that I can use the perfectly command:

```
wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO - --bind-address 10.200.21.3
```

However all have a problem, I need the static IP interface (in the example `10.200.21.3`), but the pptp server sends me a dynamic IP, is there any way to simulate it?

Answer (score 1):

Check your PPTP Server configuration (`/etc/ppp/chap-secrets`).  Place the static IP under the `IP address` column.

Example:

Change from:

```
# *     *       ""      *
# Secrets for authentication using CHAP
# client        server  secret                  IP addresses
MyUser    pptpd    mypassword   *
```

Change to:

```
# *     *       ""      *
# Secrets for authentication using CHAP
# client        server  secret                  IP addresses
MyUser    pptpd    mypassword   10.200.21.3
```

This resolution uses a matching pair of client (`/etc/pptp/peers/peername`) and server (`/etc/pptp/chap-secrets`).  Quick setup can be found at:
http://faq.apollo3.com/ljames/ubuntu/vpn/

Comment: I tried this, however unsuccessfully, the interface ip continue to change

Comment: Aug 24 09:03:14  pppd[982]: MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled
Aug 24 09:03:14  pppd[982]: local  IP address 10.200.21.4
Aug 24 09:03:14  pppd[982]: remote IP address 10.200.20.1

Comment: What do you get when you use `sudo poff` and `sudo pon [pptp-server]` to start your VPN connection?

Comment: No results, however if I type this command "sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog" I can see the log of the connection that is this [link](http://pastebin.com/3VWn8WPW)

Comment: the ip is returned by the pptp server, server this is paid and I do not have access to change, any solution using this same server?

Comment: It's up to the server administrator whether to provide a dynamic or static IP.  If you were the server administrator you would set it up that way.  Or put in a request to the server administrator for the specifics.